# How to detect that jquery autocomplete is not selected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I wonder if anyone can help me with an issue I'm having validating an autocomplete field in jQuery.

Scenario as follows, I click on a box and start typing, I then type outside the dropdown of values (so only the letters I've typed get selected). I then click next and the field validates ok (it checks that a count is over 0 (i.e. at least one spare part has been added) and it checks if the field is not empty).

Although in my example I'm handling multiple input fields the same principle also applies to when a single box is selected. I'm using jQuery 1.11.2.min.js jquery.validate.js and jquery.autocomplete.js, probably no use in answering the question but I'm also using bootstrap:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.sparedesc', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'func_action/autocomplete_spares_search.php',
        selectFirst: true,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            console.log(suggestion);
            showSparesWarning(suggestion.value.length);
        }
    });
});
```

My function in autocomplete_spares_search.php returns the data as needed and a dropdown is displayed with the possible selections. However if I click outside the box (ie closing it and not using any provided option) then only the letters I've typed are in the input box (clicking an option in the dropdown replaces the typed text with the selected option. So I'm unable to validate that the autocomplete field is correct. Any ideas?

Also I'm a bit stuck on how to validate multiple inputs so any pointers to good recent tuts on this would be appreciated too.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked into my issue further and think I have 2 possible methods, firstly (and probably least desirable due to another ajax call) would be to check that the selected field exists in the database via a new function or alternatively i add a data-selected="1" attribute to the input when successfully changed and check this count matches the class element count.